# How can I use Flask_SocketIO to emit from within another websocket connection?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to emit an event from my backend to the front-end using flask_socketio. Concurrently I have another websocket connection to aisstream.com to consume data. I would like to send the data from this aisstream connection to my frontend but socketio.emit() calls are not making it out of my connect_ais_stream() coroutine.

Backend `app.py`:

```
thread = None
thread_lock = Lock()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

async def connect_ais_stream():

    async with websockets.connect("wss://stream.aisstream.io/v0/stream") as websocket:
        subscribe_message = {"APIKey": "secret",
                             "BoundingBoxes": [[[49.233418, -123.524019], [49.374737, -122.954265]]],
                             "FilterMessageTypes": ["PositionReport"]}

        subscribe_message_json = json.dumps(subscribe_message)
        await websocket.send(subscribe_message_json)

        async for message_json in websocket:
            message = json.loads(message_json)
            print(message) # This will print to console
            socketio.emit("newBoatLocated", {"value": message}) # This wont make it to the frontend
            

"""
Serve root index file
"""
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

"""
Decorator for connect
"""
@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(asyncio.run(connect_ais_stream()))
            

"""
Decorator for disconnect
"""
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected',  request.sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Relevant frontend `app.js`

```
socket.on("newBoatLocated", function (msg) {
  console.log(msg.value);
});
```

I imagine mixing coroutines and sockets is a messy subject, any help would be appreciated!

I expect the socket to emit properly to be able to catch it in the frontend as it does when I send static data through a test function. However the boat data is never sent.

**SOLVED**

So the workaround was to change the `app.py` main call to `start_background_task` to a synchronous function that from within that called my asyncio.run() function, like so:

```
"""
Decorator for connect
"""
@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)

async def connect_ais_stream():

    async with websockets.connect("wss://stream.aisstream.io/v0/stream") as websocket:
        subscribe_message = {"APIKey": "secret",
                             "BoundingBoxes": [[[49.233418, -123.524019], [49.374737, -122.954265]]],
                             "FilterMessageTypes": ["PositionReport"]}

        subscribe_message_json = json.dumps(subscribe_message)
        await websocket.send(subscribe_message_json)

        async for message_json in websocket:
            message = json.loads(message_json)
            print(message)
            socketio.emit("newBoatLocated", {"value": message})

def background_thread():
    asyncio.run(connect_ais_stream())
```